# Shorthand adding/appending in Python

Tags: python

I like that in PHP I can do the following

```
$myInteger++;
$myString += 'more text';
```

With Python I must do the following

```
myInteger = myInteger + 1
myString = myString + "more text"
```

Is there a better way to add or append to a variable in Python?

Comment: One rule in the Zen of Python is there should be one, and only one way to do something.  += and ++ are redundant, and ++ is actually only useful for numbers, += is useful for strings, numbers, dates, etc.

Comment: And that saves me asking a followup question, thanks! I'll find an answer of yours to upvote in thanks :)

Comment: The reason ++ was left out is that Python doesn't allow modifying variables in the middle of an expression, so then ++ doesn't offer any advantage over += 1 when it has to be written on its own line.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Python doesn't have the increment (++) and decrement (--) operators, but it does have the += operator (and -=, etc.) so you can do this:

```
myInteger += 1
myString += "more text"
```

Comment: @Teifion: and yay twice for never skimming through the Python documentation.

Comment: Side note: you should generally prefer ''.join(['some', 'more text', 'to add']) to += for strings with more than 2 components.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in the same way you are doing it in PHP:

```
var += 1
```

But my advice is to write it down clear:

```
var = var + 1
```

Comment: I find the first one is WAY clearer. And it avoids a possible typo where you would accidently do something else than increment var.

Comment: The first one is definitely clearer & cleaner. I'd take another look and reconsider.

Comment: I wouldn't down vote someone for saying it's subjective, but correct opinion.

Comment: If you think that var = var + 1 is not clear, you don't understand how computers work.